# how to get optional value in dropdown list dictionary

Tags: c#

Below is my code. i am binding drop down list to a dictionary object. i want to set a optional value to it.

```
List<TextCategory> d = new List<TextCategory>();

d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "1", Text = "Skola: landstinget" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "2", Text = "Skola: kommunen" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "3", Text = "Särskola: landstinget" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "4", Text = "Särskola: kommunen" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "5", Text = "Ej aktuellt (dvs inget av ovanstående ska visas)" });
return d;
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Where is dictionary? and what do you mean by optional value

Comment: i have initialised dictionary object in my code..

Comment: i have initialised dictionary object in my code..optional value means say text as "Select"

Comment: if i want to set a default text to "Särskola: landstinget" then how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I normally just add a dummy value as an item in the list. You can handle the selection of the optional item by testing for `CategoryId == ""` elsewhere in your code.

It might look something like this:

```
List<TextCategory> d = new List<TextCategory>();
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "", Text = "- Välj -" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "1", Text = "Skola: landstinget" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "2", Text = "Skola: kommunen" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "3", Text = "Särskola: landstinget" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "4", Text = "Särskola: kommunen" });
d.Add(new TextCategory() { CategoryId = "5", Text = "Ej aktuellt (dvs inget av ovanstående ska visas)" });
return d;
```

(assuming that "Välj" means "Select" :-)

Comment: but how can i set that default value to Valj?

Comment: You'll need to tell us what type of application you're building. Is it a web app? Windows app?

Comment: its a c# web application

Comment: if i want to set a default text to "Särskola: landstinget" then how can i achieve it?

Comment: Do you know whether you're using web forms or MVC in your C# web application? The approach to binding and setting a default value will be different in each.